# Cache-control header gets ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-cloudfront

I have a problem with my cache header. I've managed to configure Cloudfront to serve my static assets but I would also like to store those assets in the cache but my cache-control header won't work.

Cache-control header in production.rb

```
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=31536000"
```

Response from curl -i

```
content-type: image/svg+xml
content-length: 1109
server: Cowboy
date: Fri, 17 Apr 2020 15:40:47 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 23 Oct 2018 06:20:26 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
via: 1.1 vegur, 1.1 36977a6510529cb59329604bc8295569.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
x-amz-cf-pop: CPH50-C1
x-amz-cf-id: u16cAiiGFzz_Tw7UWYGH6DNLqUgAy0pVM7cgzJYLXmvTYAGR6LVpbw==
```

I expect a line like `cache-control: public, max-age=31536000"`

Is there something more I need to add?

Comment: This might be pretty obvious but did you restart/redeploy your app?

Comment: @max If deploying to Heroku restarts the app I did.